# How to persist a variable between renders in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I've got a variable `dog` that I want to persist between re-renders.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  greet() {
    alert(`Hello I'm ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

const Dog = () => {
  let dog;
  useEffect(() => {
    dog = new Animal("Rusty", 5);
  }, []);
  return <button onClick={() => dog.greet()}>Greet</button>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(1);

  return (
    <main>
      <p>{num}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(num + 1)}>Add 1</button>
      <br />
      <Dog />
    </main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#react-container"));
```

```html
<div id="react-container"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

In the snippet above there's the `dog` variable that I want to persist between re-renders. On the first render `Dog` component works fine and the `alert` is triggered successfully on clicking the `Greet` button.

But once there's a re-render which can be forced by clicking the `Add 1` button, the `dog` variable is reset and now there's no greet method on it, so clicking `Greet` button throws an  error.

I fixed this by using the `useRef` hook, just wanted to know if there's some better alternative or `useRef` is the best practice here.

So, I modified the `Dog` component to the following:

```
const Dog = () => {
  let dog = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    dog.current = new Animal("Rusty", 5);
  }, []);
  return <button onClick={() => dog.current.greet()}>Greet</button>;
};
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  greet() {
    alert(`Hello I'm ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

const Dog = () => {
  let dog = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    dog.current = new Animal("Rusty", 5);
  }, []);
  return <button onClick={() => dog.current.greet()}>Greet</button>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(1);

  return (
    <main>
      <p>{num}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(num + 1)}>Add 1</button>
      <br />
      <Dog />
    </main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#react-container"));
```

```html
<div id="react-container"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: `useState(dog)` ?

Comment: `const [dog, setDog] = useState();`

Comment: @Evert No, you want to store in the state variables that should trigger renders, but if you want to keep other variables around, useRef is the way to go.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee In my opinion, yes. As the doc says also: It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's understand line by line what's happening with the first implementation of the `Dog` functional component.

```
1. const Dog = () => {
2.   let dog;
3.   useEffect(() => {
4.     dog = new Animal("Rusty", 5);
5.   }, []);
6.   return <button onClick={() => dog.greet()}>Greet</button>;
7. };
```

- In line no. 2 we define a variable named `dog`, nice and simple.
- From line no. 3 to 5, we call the `useEffect` hook and pass in a callback function to it. The callback has a closure over the variable `dog` that we created in line no. 1. 
  Also, since we have passed `[]` as dependency array this means the callback will only be called once when the component is mounted.
- Finally in line no. 6 we return a button whose `onClick` handler also has a closure over the same `dog` variable.

### `Dog` component on mount

When the `Dog` component is called for the first time (on mount) following things happen:

1. `dog` variable is created.
2. `useEffect` hook is called and a callback is passed (note that the callback is just passed and not called).
3. A button is returned.
4. And finally the `useEffect` callback passed in step 2 is called and because it has a closure over the `dog` variable, the same `dog` variable that was created in step one get's updated to store an instance of the `Animal` class (i.e. `new Animal("Rusty", 5)`).

### Greet button is clicked

Now, when the "Greet" button is clicked, it's `onClick` handler is called, which has closure over the same `dog` variable which got updated to "Rusty", therefore we get the expected alert on the screen.

### `Dog` component on second render

When the `Dog` component is called again (by making state changes in the parent component) following things happen:

1. A **new** `dog` variable is created.
2. `useEffect` hook is called and a callback is passed, but note that this callback will never be called because of how the dependency array is set up.
3. Finally a button is returned whose `onClick` handler now has a closure over the **new** `dog` variable.

### Greet button is clicked again

Now when the "Greet" button is clicked again, the `onClick` handler is called, which now has a closure over the new `dog` variable and this time the variable is `undefined`, so we get an error.

So, the point to note here is that with functional component every time there's a re-render all the variables inside the function get re-created and closures over these variables also get updated.

## Solution

The solution with `useRef` is good enough, `useRef` offers the following two things:

1. It's value persists between re-renders.
2. And it can be mutated without causing a re-render.

But in this case the solution can be made even better by moving the `dog` variable out of the component.

**This solution works really well if you want to instantiate a library once and then call methods on that instance inside your component.**

```js
const { useState } = React;

class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  greet() {
    alert(`Hello I'm ${this.name}!`);
  }
}

const dog = new Animal("Rusty", 5);

const Dog = () => {
  return <button onClick={() => dog.greet()}>Greet</button>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(1);

  return (
    <main>
      <p>{num}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setNum(num + 1)}>Add 1</button>
      <br />
      <Dog />
    </main>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#react-container"));
```

```html
<div id="react-container"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

On a sidenote, `useMemo` should not be used for this, it is only meant for optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As it is needed to load a library, it is better to persist it in the React Context, so it can be used in other components too:

Context:

```
import { ReactNode, useState } from 'react';

const ApiRegister = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [api, setApi] = useState(null);

  const registerApi = api => setApi(api);

  return (
    <ApiContext.Provider
      value={{
        api,
        registerApi,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ApiContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ApiRegister;
```

Saving API to context:

```
const ApiInitializer = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { api, registerApi }: ContextType = useContext(ApiContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const api = initializeApi();
    api.then(api => registerApi(api));
  }, [dispatch, registerApi]);


  return (
    <Component />
  );
};

export default ApiInitializer;
```

**Old answer:**

[useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) could be a good solution here, seems cleaner than refs:

```
const Dog = () => {
  const dog = useMemo(() => new Animal('Rusty', 5), []);

  return <button onClick={() => dog.greet()}>Greet</button>;
};
```

Comment: I like the solution +1, But is it just cleaner or it has other advantages as well?

Comment: Refs are mostly used for persisting DOM elements when interacting directly to DOM, so it seems overkill here. Also `useMemo` seems more self-explanatory here about what you are trying to do. For maintainability `useMemo` gives more options when to update the object in the future if needed.

Comment: ```useMemo``` should be used only for optimization (has the docs/core devs says), not for keeping variables instances. Also: ```it seems overkill here```, really ? What's the argument ?

Comment: Honestly, it does not seem clear from the code why keeping variables instance is needed,  and what is the scope of the app. But in different situations(and situations can change!), different solutions might work. There could be situations when Refs is a better choice, but that is up to the question's author to decide :)

Comment: Yes, but you are making wrong assumptions about useRef when you say it's overkill, or less cleaner than useMemo. And you're using it wrong at useMemo  should be used ```only``` for optimization.

Comment: @Shota So, I am using a third party audio library that needs to instantiated once and then there are several methods available on that instance (like play/pause, skip etc) that would be used based on user interactions. So, I guess the example illustrates that quite well.

Comment: @som-shekhar-mukherjee thanks for the explanation, in that case in the long term Context seems to be the best choice so you can use the instantiated library functions in other components too.

Comment: @HaJa react-table for example uses `useMemo` for the purpose of data not to be recreated on every render:  https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start

Comment: @Shota Yep they use it as optimization for every renders, like what I said. ```You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.``` I think the doc is clear enough :)